# Improvements of Openflow 1.5 versus Openflow 1.4

Tags: openflow

I have found specifications for [openflow 1.5](https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-switch-v1.5.1.pdf) and [openflow 1.4](https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-spec-v1.4.0.pdf) and they can't seem to have a change log, is there any change log available to know the enhancements of the new version?

Answer (score 0):

In the [OpenFlow 1.5.1](https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-switch-v1.5.1.pdf) document linked in your question, Appendix B, "Release Notes", describes the changes made between OpenFlow versions. Section B.19 on page 277 describes the changes made between OpenFlow 1.4.1 and OpenFlow 1.5.0. You can also view the changes between prior OpenFlow versions in Sections B.1 through B.18.